# Ical4j. RFC5545. Calculate event occurrences with exclusion

Tags: java, groovy, rfc5545, recurring-events, ical4j

I check *[ical4j](https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j)* library. At time I need calculate event occurrences. Useful example to calculate is [here](https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j/blob/develop/src/test/groovy/net/fortuna/ical4j/model/VEventRecurrenceTest.groovy). I try to add exclusion

```
    VEvent event = new ContentBuilder().vevent {
        dtstart('20101113', parameters: parameters() {value('DATE')})
        dtend('20101114', parameters: parameters() {value('DATE')})
        rrule('FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=MO;INTERVAL=3;BYDAY=MO,TU,SA')
        // I've added next row, the value is present in result occurrences
        exdate('20101221T000000Z/P1D')
    }
    def dates = event.calculateRecurrenceSet(new Period('20101101T000000/20110101T000000'))
    println dates
```

But occurrences calculation does not changed. Can anyone fix me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't include:

```
/P1D
```

To exclude one date you can use the following:

```
exdate('20101221T000000Z')
```

Providing you need to exclude more than one date, you can separate them by comma:

```
exdate('20101129T000000Z,20101221T000000Z')
```